# setup Intel Graphics 4000 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware

when I try to run Vmware View Client it says to me : "This Desktop does not support the requested display protocol."

I searched for it and found that i have to setup video graphics , I tried to install additional driver but the system does not find or recognize any additional drivers.

how can i solve this please ?